# Composite C1 site shows installation dialog instead of actual site

Tags: c1-cms

I've copied a live Composite C1 CMS based website to a local location to work on. Instead of seeing the site content I'm being taken to the installation dialog pages as if I'm installing a new Composite C1 site from scratch. Any ideas what's going on?

I'm running:
Composite C1 3.2 Patch 3
Build no. 3.2.4681.14221

It's running on IIS 8.5 locally and I believe the live shared hosting server is running IIS 6.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: 1. Have you copied all the files in ~/App_Data/Composite/Configuration/. 2. Was the original website XML-based?

Comment: I believed I had FTP'd the entire site down, but your comment made me realise not the entire App_Data directory had come down! I guess this was the issue - re-downloading now and will report back on result. Site is XML based. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the FTP'ing of files terminated prematurely and a number of files had been missed. Once these files where pulled across everything worked as expected.

Comment: You can install and use the XML-Based Site Backup add-on http://www.composite.net/Add-on-Market/Packages/Composite.Tools.XmlBasedSiteBackup if you website is XML-based. When it is backed up, you can downloaded it as a ZIP file and use it wherever you need